# Display IPS glow on DELL xps 13 (9333)

Tags: laptop, display, dell-xps

I have this ips glow (google's name) on my laptop's monitor when displaying the black color.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Is that a common prolem? Is it normal?

My laptop is under warranty (1 year). I contacted DELL, and after a bit of software debug, they will send a technician.

Is this problem covered by the warranty?

Thank you very much for your answes!

Comment: We don't know what they will say or if they will replace it. Super User's Q&A format is good for solving actual issues, not speculating.

Comment: The problem (in this accentuated form) is covered by the warranty and the technician replaced the monitor with a new one. However, like ap0 said a little of Backlight Bleeding is still present in the new monitor. But very much less than it was before. Now I'm happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there is Backlight Bleeding, not IPS Glow.

Unfortunatly Backlight Bleeding is common on IPS and other LCD Screens. Some have only little some have quite a lot. My QNIX QX2710LED (Korea) has it to but is not as bad as in your pictures.

There are possible fixes for this issue. But this invovles disassembling the screen and placing for example black tape around the panel such that the light is blocked. But I wouldn't recommend this on an Laptop and specially not if you still have warranty. 
You could try gently tapping on the spots and in some cases this will lessen the effect. But probably not get rid of it.

The question wether DELL will replace the screen/Laptop because of Backlight Bleeding (BB) is diffecult. Little BB is common and if it is not too much and I don't think they will fix it. But yours (judging by the pictures) is quite a lot and they might replace it. Maybe it depends on the kindness of the technician which will visit you.

Generally speaking, a certain amount of BB is common on this panels and if it isn't too much, it is not a warranty case.